# MySQL find and replace values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
company  | description   
---------------------------------
Google   | a great search engine
Youtube  | request description from Youtube.
Facebook | connect with friends!
Netflix  | request description from Netflix.
```

Basically, I want to delete all cells in the description containing `request description from` so the table ends up like:

```
company  | description   
---------------------------------
Google   | a great search engine
Youtube  | 
Facebook | connect with friends!
Netflix  |
```

I know I can ADD FULLTEXT and do a MATCH, but I'm wondering if there is an easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the operator LIKE in the UPDATE statement:

```
update tablename
set description = null
where description like '%request description from%'
```

Comment: or `set description = ''`

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
select company,
       (case when description not like '%request description from%' then description end) as description
from t;
```

If you want to actually change the data, use `update`:

update t
set description = null
where description like '%request description from%';